# OpenGL Misreading UniformBuffer in ComputeShader

Tags: opengl, buffer, transform, compute-shader, uniform

I was doing a test of new way of transforming vertex positions in compute shader for some reason and I encountered a problem. What I want is just transforming the vertex (whose id is 2) 1.0f up but after the compute shader the vertex has always been transformed 1.2f right with same height.

I checked the shaders storage buffer and uniform buffer several times by Nvidia Nsight and buffer datas looked good.

ComputeShader

```
#version 460 core

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform Matrix 
{
    float u_id;
    mat4 modelM;
};


struct VertexLayout 
{
    vec3 positions;
    float v_id;
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer VertexBuffer 
{
    VertexLayout vertex[];
};


void main() 
{
    if(vertex[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].v_id == u_id) 
    {
        vertex[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].positions = vec3(modelM * vec4(vertex[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].positions, 1.0));
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Test1.h"

Renderer* renderer;

int main()
{
    if (!InitGLFW())
        return -1;
    
    renderer = new Renderer();
    renderer->loadMatrix();
    

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer->Render();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    delete renderer;
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
        case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
            break;

        case GLFW_KEY_KP_1:
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
            break;

        case GLFW_KEY_KP_2:
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
            break;

        case GLFW_KEY_KP_4:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            break;

        case GLFW_KEY_KP_5:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
            break;

        case GLFW_KEY_KP_6:
            renderer->Transform();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Test1

```
#pragma once
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"

struct Data
{
    float id;
    glm::mat4 modelM;
};

class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer();
    ~Renderer();

    void loadMatrix();
    void Render();
    void Transform();
    Data data;

private:
    unsigned int shaderID;
    unsigned int programID;
    unsigned int vertexBufferID;
    unsigned int vertexArrayID;
    unsigned int uniformBufferID;

    unsigned int vertexShader;
    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    unsigned int prog;

};



#include "Test1.h"
#include "IO.h"
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include <iostream>


Renderer::Renderer()
{
    shaderID = ShaderIO::loadShaderFromFile("resource\\shaders\\Test1\\compute.glsl", GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);

    vertexShader = ShaderIO::loadShaderFromFile("resource\\shaders\\Test1\\vertex.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShader = ShaderIO::loadShaderFromFile("resource\\shaders\\Test1\\fragment.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(prog, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(prog, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glValidateProgram(prog);


    programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, shaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programID);
    glValidateProgram(programID);

    int isValid;
    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &isValid);
    if (!isValid)
    {
        std::cout << "[ERROR]: Program is not valid!" << std::endl;
        glDeleteProgram(programID);
        glDeleteShader(shaderID);
    }


    float positions[] = 
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 2.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 3.0f
    };

    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertexArrayID, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vertexArrayID, 0, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vertexArrayID, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

    glCreateBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glNamedBufferData(vertexBufferID, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertexArrayID, 0, vertexBufferID, 0, 4 * sizeof(float));

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
    glUseProgram(prog);

    glCreateBuffers(1, &uniformBufferID);
    glNamedBufferData(uniformBufferID, sizeof(Data), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, uniformBufferID);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, vertexBufferID);

    data.id = 2;
    data.modelM = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
}

Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteShader(shaderID);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uniformBufferID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteProgram(prog);
}

void Renderer::loadMatrix()
{
    glNamedBufferSubData(uniformBufferID, 0, sizeof(Data), &data);
}

void Renderer::Render()
{
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

void Renderer::Transform()
{
    glUseProgram(programID);
    glDispatchCompute(3, 1, 1);
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(prog);
}
```

I have tried so many things and finally I found that when I exclude the u_id from uniform buffer and changed the size to just mat4's size, it worked! On the other hand, I don't know why it does not work with u_id and I have to use it. Please Help!

This is uniform buffer memory
[image: This is uniform buffer memory]

This is shader stroge buffer memory after compute shader
[image: This is shader stroge buffer memory]

Comment: A `mat4` or `vec4` is aligned to 16 bytes. This is specified in `std140`: *"If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 2N or 4N, respectively."*. See [Uniform Blocks](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

Comment: WOW, I didn't know that. It worked thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `std140` standard, a member of type `mat4` or `vec4` is aligned to 16 bytes. This is specified in the OpenGL specification See [Uniform Blocks](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=166&zoom=100,168,308):

> 2. If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 2N or 4N, respectively.
>    [...]
> 3. If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment and array
>    stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array element, according
>    to rules (1), (2), and (3), and rounded up to the base alignment of a vec4. The
>    array may have padding at the end; the base offset of the member following
>    the array is rounded up to the next multiple of the base alignment.
> 4. If the member is a column-major matrix with C columns and R rows, the
>    matrix is stored identically to an array of C column vectors with R components each, according to rule (4).